# why my image editor script says syntax error

Tags: php

I am trying to create my image editor site but I face a lot of problems in making this site. The problem is that it says syntax error when I upload it to my web hosting site.

---

```
 <?
    include_once('ImageEditor.php');
    $src = new ImageEditor();
    $dst = new ImageEditor();
    $dst->createCanvas(200, 400);
    $src->loadImageFile('nalin.jpg' );
    $dst->fillin($src, 0, 1000);
    $drop = new ImageEditor();
    $drop->loadImageFile('1.jpg');
    #$dst->dropin($drop, 20 ,50);
    $dst->fillinArea($drop, 10, 20, 100, 100);
    $dst->fillinArea($drop, 10, 350, 100, 100);
    #$src->rotate(90);
    #$dst->fitin($src);
    #$dst->applyGrayscale();
    #$dst->pseudosepia(20);
    #$dst->sepia(60);
    #$dst->grayscale();
    $dst->writeImageFile('out.jpg', ImageEditor::JPG, 75);
    #$src->writeImageFile('out.jpg', ImageEditor::JPG, 75);
    #$dst->displayImage('JPG');
    ?>
```

*And my **ImageEditor.php** is taken from GitHub you easily [check this][1].*

---

I face a error when I upload it to my web hosting site:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'ImageEditor' not found in **/home/a2226731/public_html/image.php** on line **3**

Comment: [Please don't post your code/exceptions as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Comment: Are you sure `ImageEditor.php` exists? Check CaPiToLiZaTiOn, it matters on linux machines (But not windows machines).

Comment: Oh c'mon - PHP even **tells** you what the error is *Class 'ImageEditor' not found ...* i.e. your `include_once` path is wrong; on a technical note, since that class is **required** you should probably use *require_once*.

Answer (score 1):

According to your github ImageEditor.php path is inside lib/ folder. Use

```
require_once('lib/ImageEditor.php')
```

instead of

```
include_once('ImageEditor.php');
```